# Accessing properties from multiple classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application and I have two classes:

```
public class MOrderMain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string BillingName { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryName { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class MOrder
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int OrhID { get; set; }
   public int ProID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public double Rate { get; set; }
   public double Amount { get; set; }
   public int DeliveredQty { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to retrieve details from both classes. For example, I want to get
`ID` and `Billing Name` from class `MorderMain` and all the properties from class `MOrder`. How can I do this?

I am getting the values by database. I have the query but how will I assign the data and how will I retrieve from both?

```
var mylist = new List<MOrder>();
_con = _db.GetConnection();
if (_con.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
{
    _con.Open();
}
_cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_All_Order_Details", _con) 
           { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
_dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (_dr.Read())
{
    mylist.Add(new MOrder
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordID"]),
        OrhID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["orhID"]),
        ProID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["proID"]),
        Name = _dr["pName"].ToString(),
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordQty"]),
        Rate = Convert.ToDouble(_dr["ordRate"]),
        Amount = Convert.ToDouble(_dr["ordAmount"]),
        DeliveredQty = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordQtyDelivered"])
     });
}
return mylist;
```

Comment: In order to answer your question, you need to show how is the data coming back from the stored procedure. Are you doing an inner join between the OrderMain and the Order tables or are you selecting from both tables and returning 2 result sets, one with the "order header" (OrderMain) and one with all the order items (Order)?

Comment: I am joining and returning the data that is specific. mean by joining from two tables i am getting ID,Billing Data, and rest order details perfectly. i just need to know weather the approach is correct and how can i avoid making duplicate properties

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving data from both tables in your database but want to combine them in your application, the solution would be to create a single class that contains the data you return from your stored procedure:

```
public class MAllOrderDetails
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string BillingName { get; set; }
   // include the other billing details you want here

   public int OrhID { get; set; }
   public int ProID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public double Rate { get; set; }
   public double Amount { get; set; }
   public int DeliveredQty { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your query changes to filling in a `List<MAllOrderDetails>`.

This leaves your application with only dealing with a collection of a single class with all the data nicely contained in single objects.

```
var mylist = new List<MAllOrderDetails>();
//...
while (_dr.Read())
{
    mylist.Add(new MAllOrderDetails
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordID"]),
        BillingName = _dr["BillingName"].ToString(),
        // etc.
        OrhID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["orhID"]),
        ProID = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["proID"]),
        Name = _dr["pName"].ToString(),
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordQty"]),
        Rate = Convert.ToDouble(_dr["ordRate"]),
        Amount = Convert.ToDouble(_dr["ordAmount"]),
        DeliveredQty = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["ordQtyDelivered"])
     });
}
```

**Update**

You could probably get away with this as the closest solution to not creating an additional classes:

```
class MAllOrderDetails
{
    public MOrder Order { get; set; }
    public MOrderMain OrderMain { get; set; }
}
```

I feel, though, that from a maintainability standpoint, this will cause you more headaches than just creating additional classes.

Comment: I have this Way but i want to keep the classes different. Is there any way that i can do inheritance or interface ?

Comment: @MoizKachwala, I don't think inheritance or using interfaces will help you with this, but I have updated my answer to include the only solution I can think of to limit the number of classes you have. I still recommend creating a new class, even if it duplicates some properties of other classes, because it will be much easier to maintain. Trying to save on duplicating classes up front is going to cost you later on as you try to work with them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i did that way by creating a new class and i make some field duplicate.